# Hover to show a reveal.js slide?

Tags: reveal.js

I am trying to use jquery to show different `reveal.js` slides as I hover over several links.

I have tried and it works by clicking by giving an id to the slide and `href='#/01'` to a link, and it works.

For example:
Link:

```
<a class="link" href='#/01'>This links to section id="01".</a>
```

Slide:

```
<section id="01">
Text here.
</section>
```

But I can't get the hover to work for example using:

```
<script>$(".link").hover(function() { $("#01").fadeToggle();});</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].